# SQL ALTER TABLE on TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 tables that look like :

```
  TABLE_1                         TABLE_2
ID      NAME                     ID      object1       object2                

1      object1                   1        TRUE          FALSE
2      object1                   2        TRUE          TRUE
2      object2
```

I want that for each new Object on TABLE_1, it add a column on TABLE_2. And for each new ID on TABLE_1, it add a new Occurence on TABLE_2 (but I know how to do "only" this one).

For exemple with `INSERT INTO TABLE_1 values(1,"object3");`
I want

```
  TABLE_1                    TABLE_2
ID      NAME               ID      object1       object2       object3               

1      object1             1        TRUE          FALSE         TRUE
2      object1             2        TRUE          TRUE          FALSE
2      object2                    
1      object3
```

and with `INSERT INTO TABLE_1 values(3,"object2);`

```
  TABLE_1                    TABLE_2
ID      NAME               ID      object1       object2       object3               

1      object1             1        TRUE          FALSE         TRUE
2      object1             2        TRUE          TRUE          FALSE
2      object2             3        FALSE         TRUE          FALSE                    
1      object3
3      object2
```

It's not necessary to fill the added column (I can do it manually).

I tried to do this

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggTest 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON TABLE_1 
WHEN (NEW.NAME not in (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE_1))
BEGIN 
ALTER TABLE TABLE_2
ADD NEW.NAME BOOLEAN
END;
```

But it didn't work... Can you help me ?
(And sorry if my english isn't perfect)

Comment: I think you should renew your design of your database. Alter table on an insert is not seems legit for me.

Comment: The syntax looks like MySQL, so I removed the mysql tag.

Comment: If you know another way to have the TABLE_2 as I showed it, so I could be able to renew the design... Currently I don't see other way to do it

Comment: Why is object2 FALSE for ID 2?

Comment: I just failed, It's TRUE now. Thank you

Comment: Your Table_2 is essentially a pivoted select of the data from Table_1, isn't it? I suspect it's for presentation purposes only, so why just not use the PIVOT operator when selecting?

Comment: I didn't know the PIVOT operator. Thank you :)

Comment: There was an SQL Server tag when I commented. Not sure if MySQL has a PIVOT operator or not, but if not, it could be simulated with a couple of CASE expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need more tables to achieve what you want.

Table IDs should be unique. "TABLE_1" IDs that are not unique should be kept in another table as Primary Keys, then your "TABLE_1" table could reference that other table containing those IDs as ForeignKeys.

Your "TABLE_2" table looks like it should be split into two: one that would contain your "Objects", and one that associates "Objects" and "IDs".

Or is it only a view of "TABLE_1", displayed differently? Then you can just drop it.

Please read about [Junction tables](http://The%20error%20is%20not%20only%20on%20the%20UPDATE.%20Oracle%20shout%20from%20the%20first%20SELECT.%20He%20doesn't%20want%20that%20I%20Read/Write%20on%20Pile%20during%20a%20trigger%20on%20Pile), and SQL and Relational databases in general, because you need more knowledge before starting your project.